# Empty set state what is the point?

Tags: flutter, setstate

I want to know the point behind calling `setState` without setting a new value to the variables.

```
  readLocal() async {
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    id = prefs.getString('id') ?? '';
    if (id.hashCode <= peerId.hashCode) {
      groupChatId = '$id-$peerId';
    } else {
      groupChatId = '$peerId-$id';
    }

    setState(() {});
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does setState take a closure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44379366/why-does-setstate-take-a-closure)

Comment: usually just to rebuild without changing any variables.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would say it's just a **convention**. The above can be re-written as

```
readLocal() async {
  prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  setState(() {
    id = prefs.getString('id') ?? '';
    if (id.hashCode <= peerId.hashCode) {
      groupChatId = '$id-$peerId';
    } else {
     groupChatId = '$peerId-$id';
   }
  });
}
```

Both will do the same thing. Calling `setState(() {})` after mutating the `state variable` looks neat and reabable.

As per the [implementation](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html) section of `setState`, it will below things in order.

1. Assertions. If any assert fails, throws exception and stops there.
2. Execute the **callback function** (`final dynamic result = fn() as dynamic;`)
3. Ask framework to **rebuild**(`_element.markNeedsBuild();`)

Comment: Empty `setState` usage should be avoided. https://medium.com/@mehmetf_71205/setting-the-state-2809936fb79d

Answer (score 3):

The documentation says [ https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html ]:

> Calling setState notifies the framework that the internal state of this object has changed in a way that might impact the user interface in this subtree, which causes the framework to schedule a build for this State object.

The empty bracket `{ }` is the empty callback (because you apparently don't need one):

> The provided callback is immediately called synchronously. [...]

In short:

```
setState(() {});
```

is a way to tell the framework to build the state object anew, without using the possibility to pass a callback which would be called right after the build

Comment: The style guide (somewhere) says not to do this, because it should be clear from looking at the `setState` about *why* you are calling it, and if things get refactored such that the code is no longer needed here, the corresponding `setState` call can also be refactored out.

Comment: I think "right after the build" part is not correct. It should be "just before rebuilding".

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Style-guide-for-Flutter-repo#comment-empty-closures-to-setstate

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the other answers, there is one difference.

When `setState()` is called on an unmounted (`mounted == false`) widget, it will fail. This means that whatever is wrapped inside the `setState` callback won't be called, whereas if you would run it outside `setState` it would be executed.