# Flutter - change variables inside or outside setState?

Tags: flutter

When changing the state in a Flutter Widget, are there any differences between doing this

```
_variable1 = true;
variable2 = 'abc';
setState(() => {});
```

or this

```
setState(() => {
    _variable1 = true;
    variable2 = 'abc';
});
```

Almost all the examples in the docs use the last one, but I didn't notice any pratical differences. The variables are set and the state is updated in both cases, but I am wondering if there is a scenario that something doesn't work as expected if use one or another.

Comment: It doesn't make a difference but the 2nd makes the intention more clear. The state of `_variable1`band `variable2` was changed for the purpose of updating the view.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the flutter [docs](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html), it is stated that:

> Generally it is recommended that the setState method only be used to
>   wrap the actual changes to the state, not any computation that might
>   be associated with the change.

Mainly I think that it is for readability purposes, i.e, you need to put in the body of `setState` what is changing in the new build of the widget, without mixing that with your computations as the first method in your question does.

Answer (score 10):

Already been posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52383855/11044061) this question.

It's a convetion, it doesn't matter, but, it's good pratica to wrap all the changes inside the setState function. But the results will be the same in both cases.

Answer (score 3):

I've read somewhere that an empty setState is a "code smell", because the body of the callback should indicate the reason for the setState.

Answer (score 2):

No , the result will be identical in both cases, I have used them both interchangeably in many widgets and the result was always the same.