# Putting modifying code before an empty setState versus wrapping the modifying code with the setState

Tags: flutter, dart

Assume we are creating a stateful widget with a single property (or field) as follows

```
int counter;
```

I found two ways to modify the `counter`:

- First approach

  ```
  counter++;
  setState((){}); // empty setState
  ```
- Second approach

  ```
  setState((){counter++;}); // wrapping setState
  ```

## Question

Either approach produces the same result. The updated counter are shown visually in a `Text` widget for example. I am wondering whether there are any other differences that are hard to see visually.

Comment: I would like to make a note that I retracted the answer I just posted, as I was not aware of the subtlety that calling setState in the two ways you've mentioned are meant to be equivalent. More info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52383575/empty-set-state-what-is-the-point

Comment: @DrSatan1: Thank you for the links and previous answer. I am reading... and I will decide whether it is a duplicate or not soon.