# pull down to REFRESH in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

My dashboard code looks like this,
Here I am doing get req in getReport method, I have added the `RefreshIndicator` in the code which when pulled down inside container should do the refresh, there I am calling my getData(), But I am not getting the refreshed content, I am adding my code below, let me know if anywhere I made a mistake.

below my dashboard.dart

```
class Window extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WindowState createState() => _WindowState();
}

class _WindowState extends State<Window> {
  Future reportList;    
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    reportList = getReport();
  }    

  Future<void> getReport() async {
    http.Response response =
        await http.get(reportsListURL, headers: {"token": "$token"});
    switch (response.statusCode) {
      case 200: 
        String reportList = response.body;
        var collection = json.decode(reportList);
        return collection;

      case 403:
          break;

      case 401:
        return null;

      default:
        return 1;
    }
  }

  getRefreshScaffold() {
    return Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            reportList = getReport();
          });
        },
        child: Text('Refresh, Network issues.'),
      ),
    );
  }

  getDashBody(var data) {
    double maxHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: maxHeight - 800,
        ),
        Container(
          margin: new EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
          height: maxHeight - 188,
          child: new Center(
          child: new RefreshIndicator(          //here I am adding the RefreshIndicator
          onRefresh:getReport,                  //and calling the getReport() which hits the get api
          child: createList(context, data),
          ),),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget createList(BuildContext context, var data) {
    Widget _listView = ListView.builder(
      itemCount: data.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, count) {
        return createData(context, count, data);
      },
    );
    return _listView;
  }

  createData(BuildContext context, int count, var data) {
    var metrics = data["statistic_cards"].map<Widget>((cardInfo) {
      var cardColor = getColorFromHexString(cardInfo["color"]);
      if (cardInfo["progress_bar"] != null && cardInfo["progress_bar"]) {
        return buildRadialProgressBar(
          context: context,
          progressPercent: cardInfo["percentage"],
          color: cardColor,
          count: cardInfo["value"],
          title: cardInfo["title"],
        );
      } else {
        return buildSubscriberTile(context, cardInfo, cardColor);
      }
    }).toList();

    var rowMetrics = new List<Widget>();
    for (int i = 0; i < metrics.length; i += 2) {
      if (i + 2 < metrics.length)
        rowMetrics.add(Row(children: metrics.sublist(i, i + 2)));
      else
        rowMetrics.add(Row(children: [metrics[metrics.length - 1], Spacer()]));
    }
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: LimitedBox(
        //  maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.30,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: rowMetrics,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: reportList,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.none:
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
          case ConnectionState.active:
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          case ConnectionState.done:
            var data = snapshot.data;
            if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.hasError) {
              return getDashBody(data);
            } else if (data == null) {
              return Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text("Timeout! Log back in to continue"),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                    ),
                    RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          token = null;
                        });
                        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
                          CupertinoPageRoute(
                              builder: (BuildContext context) => LoginPage()),
                        );
                      },
                      child: Text('Login Again!'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            } else {
              getRefreshScaffold();
            }
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: wrap your listview with refreshindicator its gonna work

Comment: I am not getting properly what exactly you are saying to do

Comment: Take a look at @Baker answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62206884/3550735

Answer (score 126, accepted):

## Basic Example

Below is a State class of a StatefulWidget, where:

- a `ListView` is wrapped in a `RefreshIndicator`
- `numbersList` state variable is its data source
- `onRefresh` calls `_pullRefresh` function to update data & ListView
- `_pullRefresh` is an async function, returning nothing (a `Future<void>`)
- when `_pullRefresh`'s long running data request completes, `numbersList` member/state variable is updated in a `setState()` call to rebuild `ListView` to display new data

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

class PullRefreshPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const PullRefreshPage();

  @override
  State<PullRefreshPage> createState() => _PullRefreshPageState();
}

class _PullRefreshPageState extends State<PullRefreshPage> {
  List<String> numbersList = NumberGenerator().numbers;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: RefreshIndicator(
        onRefresh: _pullRefresh,
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: numbersList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(numbersList[index]),
            );
          },),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _pullRefresh() async {
    List<String> freshNumbers = await NumberGenerator().slowNumbers();
    setState(() {
      numbersList = freshNumbers;
    });
    // why use freshNumbers var? https://stackoverflow.com/a/52992836/2301224
  }
}

class NumberGenerator {
  Future<List<String>> slowNumbers() async {
    return Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000), () => numbers,);
  }

  List<String> get numbers => List.generate(5, (index) => number);


  String get number => Random().nextInt(99999).toString();
}
```

#### Notes

- If your async `onRefresh` function completes very quickly, you may want to add an `await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));` after it, just so the UX is more pleasant.
- This gives time for the user to complete a swipe / pull down gesture & for the refresh indicator to render / animate / spin indicating data has been fetched.

---

## FutureBuilder Example

Here's another version of the above `State<PullRefreshPage>` class using a FutureBuilder, which is common when fetching data from a Database or HTTP source:

```
class _PullRefreshPageState extends State<PullRefreshPage> {
  late Future<List<String>> futureNumbersList;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureNumbersList = NumberGenerator().slowNumbers();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<List<String>>(
        future: futureNumbersList,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return RefreshIndicator(
            child: _listView(snapshot),
            onRefresh: _pullRefresh,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _listView(AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(snapshot.data[index]),
          );
        },);
    }
    else {
      return Center(
        child: Text('Loading data...'),
      );
    }
  }

  Future<void> _pullRefresh() async {
    List<String> freshNumbers = await NumberGenerator().slowNumbers();
    setState(() {
      futureNumbersList = Future.value(freshNumbers);
    });
  }
}
```

#### Notes

- `slowNumbers()` function is the same as in the **Basic Example** above, but the data is wrapped in a `Future.value()` since `FutureBuilder` expects a `Future`, but `setState()` should *not* await async data
- according to Rémi, Collin & other Dart/Flutter demigods it's good practice to update Stateful Widget member variables **inside** `setState()` (`futureNumbersList` in FutureBuilder example & `numbersList` in Basic example), *after* its long running async data fetch functions have completed.

  - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52992836/2301224
- if you try to make setState `async`, you'll get an exception
- updating member variables outside of `setState` and having an empty `setState` closure, may result in hand-slapping / code analysis warnings in the future

Comment: Perfect description and native `Flutter` solution(no dependency needed)! 

Comment: Perfect solutionThanks

Comment: Great answer. Especially nice that you explain the solution using a `FutureBuilder` as well.

Comment: The FutureBuilder example was handy and helpful !. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 15):

Not sure about futures, but for refresh indicator you must return a void so
Use something like

```
RefreshIndicator(
                onRefresh: () async  {
                  await getData().then((lA) {
                    if (lA is Future) {
                      setState(() {
                        reportList = lA;
                      });
                      return;
                    } else {
                      setState(() {
                       //error
                      });
                      return;
                    }
                  });

                  return;
                },
```

Try this and let me know!

**EDIT:**

Well, then just try this inside you refresh method

```
          setState(() {
            reportList = getReport();  
          });
          return reportList;
```

Comment: if you need the future, maybe just remove the await async params I wrote.

Comment: onRefresh: () async  {
                  await getReport().then((lA) {
                    if (lA is Future) {
                      setState(() {
                        reportList = lA;
                      });
                      return;
                    } else {
                      setState(() {
                       //error
                      });
                      return;
                    }
                  });

                  return;
                },
          child: createDashList(context, data),
          ),),
        ) ,

Comment: I have written this inside the  getDashBody but it didnt worked for me

Answer (score 4):

Easy method: you can just use Pull Down to Refresh Package - https://pub.dev/packages/pull_to_refresh

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
onRefresh: () {
  setState(() {});
}}
```

instead of `onRefresh:getReport`

`reportList` field is `Future` which returns its value once. So, when you call `getReport` again it changes nothing. Actually, more correctly it'll be with `Stream` and `StreamBuilder` instead of `Future` and `FutureBuilder`. But for this code it can be shortest solution

Comment: when changed I am getting this "Function expressions can't be named.
Try removing the name, or moving the function expression to a function declaration statement."

Comment: initially it was just getReport() , when I added the RefreshIndicator I get error saying that method should be future thing, so I renamed gerReport as => Future<void> getReport

Comment: Sorry. Edited my answer

Answer (score 3):

In Non-scrollable list view, **RefreshIndicator** does not work, so you have to wrap your widget with **Stack** for implementing pull down to refresh.

```
RefreshIndicator(
  onRefresh: () {
  // Refresh Functionality 
  },
  child: Stack(
            children: [
              ListView(
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  )
                ],
              ),
              // Your Widget 
            ],
          );
        ),
```

Comment: For me wrapping the Listview by Stack did not work but the idea of Non-scrollable is correct. I made the Listview scrollable by `physics: AlwaysScrollabelScrollPhysics` and now working :)

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a huge project which contains CustomScrollView, NestedScrollView, ListView, etc I tried every answer above and all of the answers use RefreshIndicator from flutter SDK. It doesn't work entirely with my app because I also have horizontal scroll views. So in order to implement it I had to use NestedScrollView on almost every screen. Then I came to know about [liquid_pull_to_refresh](https://pub.dev/packages/liquid_pull_to_refresh), applied it to the top widget, and WOLAAH! If you need a separate logic for each screen then use it at the top of each screen but in my case, I'm refreshing the whole project's data.