# setState(() {_counter++; }) vs setState(() {})

Tags: flutter, dart, syntax, setstate

What is the difference between putting the value that need to be updated inside the setState vs outside?

```
setState(() {
  _counter++;
});
```

and

```
_counter++;
setState(() {});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does setState take a closure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44379366/why-does-setstate-take-a-closure)

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you know what setState do, it is not the same but it do the same thing
in your case you notify the framework that the internal state of this object has changed after changing the object internal state
but if you use it as

```
setState(() {});
_counter++;
```

you might get unexpected result
if your function takes a lot time the the setState wouldn't do  anything

for example try this

```
setState(() {});
await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500));
_counter++;
```

so it dependence on the function time and place(before or after setState).
However it is better to put the value inside the setState to avoid unexpected behavior and it's the best practices for using setState as I know.

Comment: someone just upload a video about your question
here the link:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OnK679X9-0M&feature=push-u-sub&attr_tag=XFk3HWxLTusX870M%3A6
he explained better and it's just about 6 min :)